# Запуск программы при загрузке ОС Windows

Tags: windows, автозагрузка

ОС Windows Server 2008 x64 R2.
Необходимо каким-то образом автоматически запустить программу (или выполнить .bat) после перезагрузки рабочей станции (перезагружается тоже автоматически).

В планировщике задач есть такое условие, но оно срабатывает только тогда, когда кто-то входит в систему (например, через удаленный рабочий стол), и как я понял, планировщик начинает работать только тогда, когда кто-то вошел.

Может, я чего не понял, или не нашел - в общем, стоит вопрос, как автоматически выполнить что-либо при перезагрузке компъютера, без вмешательства человека.

Спасибо.

Comment: Не, планировщик должен по идее уметь всё. Посмотрите внимательнее в свойства задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно выполнять что-то без входа пользователя, то обычно используют shell скрипты, или vbs скрипты, которые конечно уже могут выполнять консольные (!) приложения, либо запускать приложения в сеансах пользователей.
По вашей же теме вот [ответ](http://windows.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7). И [вдогонку](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc721871.aspx).

А вообще для таких задач обычно используют службы, тем более на серверах. А на правильных серверах вообще linux стоят ;)